# Darken gray hair in GraphicConverter?

Tags: photo-editing, retouching, hair

I use GraphicConverter on a Mac to tweak my photos before uploading to share. Typically, I'll brighten or adjust a shadowed area or contrast, that sort of thing. Sometimes I'll hide a defect (such as a person who walked in front of a shot) by copying adjacent background over the top.

Is it possible to darken gray hair with GraphicConverter?  I've tried selecting the hair (using either lasso or polygon selector) and then darkening the selection or adjusting the gamma, but this always ends up with a sharp line around the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Graphicconverter for OSX didn't add Dodge/Burn capabilities until version 9.2 this month. This is quite amazing that it was missing until now considering they are trying to compare to Adobe Photo shop. Using this  functionality will likely achieve what you are describing, although you could also do it with layers and fine selection of the hair depending on the image.

More info on the release:
http://fairerplatform.com/2014/05/graphicconverter-9-2-adds-sharpen-burn-dodge-brushes/

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's good to know it's now added. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on 10.6.8 for the time being (rely on apps needing Rosetta) so I'm stuck with GC 8 for now. How would using a layer be any different than what I've already tried (selecting the hair using either lasso or polygon and darkening the selection), which always ends up with a sharply defined dark border?

Comment: Can you point me at something that explains what Dodge/Burn is and how one might use it to darken gray hair or other tweaks?

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/how-do-you-use-dodge-and-burn-in-post-process-to-enhance-a-photograph